# Bash script that can uncompress: tar, gzip, rar

Tags: bash, linux

This code generally works exactly as it is supposed to. I'm learning bash I'm looking for some constructive help that could help me improve my work.

```
#!/bin/bash



usage()
{
    echo "Program for uncompressing  tar, gzip, rar archives"
    echo "Allowed parametres: --help, --file, --input, --directory"
    echo "Examples:"
    echo "./uncompress.sh --file firstFile secondFile"
    echo "./uncompress.sh --input inputFile.txt"
    echo "./uncompress.sh --directory /home/"

}


uncompress_file()
{
    if [ -f $1 ]
    then
        temp1=`file $1 | cut -d: -f2 | grep tar`

            if [ "$temp1" != "" ]
                then
                    echo    "$1 is a tar archive, uncompressing..."
                    tar xf $1 > /dev/null
            fi

        temp1=`file $1 | cut -d: -f2 | grep RAR`

            if [ "$temp1" != "" ]
                then
                    echo    "$1 is a rar archive, uncompressing..."
                    unrar e $1 > /dev/null
            fi  

        temp1=`file $1 | cut -d: -f2 | grep gzip`

            if [ "$temp1" != "" ]
                then
                    echo    "$1 is a gzip archive, uncompressing..."
                    tar xzf $1 > /dev/null

            fi


    else
    echo    "$1 is not a valid file!"
    fi
}

uncompress_dir()
{
    for file in "$1"/*
        do
            if [ -f $file ]
            then
            uncompress_file $file
            fi


            if [ -d $file ]
            then
            uncompress_dir $file
            fi


        done

}







if [ "$1" = "--help" ]
    then
    usage
    exit

fi

if test $# -lt 2
    then echo "What about parametres?" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi



param=$1;
shift;





if [ "$param" = "--file" ]
    then

        while [ $# -ne 0 ]
        do
            uncompress_file $1
            shift
        done
    exit
fi

if [ "$param" = "--input" ]
    then
        if [ -f $1 ]
            then
                while read line
                do
                    uncompress_file $line

                done < $1       
            else
                echo "$1 is not a valid file"
        fi
    exit    
fi


if [ "$param" = "--directory" ]
    then
        if [ -d $1 ]
            then
                uncompress_dir $1
            else
            echo    "$1 is not a valid directory"
        fi
    exit
fi


echo "wrong parametres!";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Don't use `cut` and `grep`, use [parameter substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) and a case statement over the file extension to decide the file type (or use the `file` command if you want to be really clever, but I recommend the former actually)
2. Don't use `[ "${foo}" != "" ]`, use `[ -n "${foo}" ]`
3. Don't mix `test` and `[`, just stick to `[` unless you want to write code that looks `autoconf` generated
4. **Quote all your variables, *especially* the ones containing filenames to account for spaces**, e.g. `tar xzf "$1" > /dev/null`
5. Don't parse command line options yourself, use `getopts` (or `getopt`, in case you really, really want GNU-style options)
6. Improve your indentation

Comment: But file extension doesn't always match content of the file. How could You deal with it then? This is why I decided to extract desired information with `file`.

Comment: My thought pattern is that if a file has the "wrong" extension, in many cases you will want to know about that and not silently continue. The decompressor should error with an appropriate message anyway. Or you could e.g. implement a `-g` (for "guess") switch to use `file` instead of the file extension. But as I said, this is a matter of preference; if you want to use `file`, go ahead ;-) As an addition source of inspiration you might want to check the `unpack` function that Gentoo's `portage` uses [here](http://git.overlays.gentoo.org/gitweb/?p=proj/portage.git;a=blob;f=bin/phase-helpers.sh).

Answer (score 3):

`grep` has a non-zero exit status if it finds no matches. So code like this

```
temp1=`file $1 | cut -d: -f2 | grep tar`
if [ "$temp1" != "" ]
then
    echo    "$1 is a tar archive, uncompressing..."
    tar xf $1 > /dev/null
fi
```

can be more succinctly written as

```
# -q causes grep to output nothing; we don't really care what it finds,
# just if it finds *something*
if file $1 | cut -d: -f2 | grep -q tar
then
    echo "$1 is a tar archive, uncompressing..."
    tar xf "$1" > /dev/null
fi
```

---

Always quote parameter expansions, as I did above for the call to `tar`, just in case the value contains whitespace. It's almost never wrong to do so, and you never know when it might be absolutely necessary.